# please tell me how to delete my P.SE account

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts

I would like to delete only my P.SE account only, but I can't find the directions anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

[This page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/user-deletion) explains how to request an account deletion.